# write tokens to external files / loop unless ifeof does not work for me

Tags: tables, external-files, loops

I'm trying to write lines including tokens to an external file and read them again in a different document. I face two prolblems:

(1) Is there a way around the ugly \unexpanded{} when calling my \filewrite command with tokens?

(2) The loop in my \parsefile{} command only reads the first line of the external file -- so there must be something wrong with the loop itself, but I can't figure it out.

Environment: updated MikTeX on Windows

Regards, Vic

**test_write.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=file.tex
\immediate\write\mywrite{Headline}

\newcommand{\filewrite}[1]{
 \immediate\write\mywrite{#1}
}

\begin{document}

Hello World!
\filewrite{11 & 12}
\filewrite{\unexpanded{21 & 22\textdegree}}
\filewrite{31 & 32}

\immediate\closeout\mywrite
\end{document}
```

**test_read.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newwrite\myread
\immediate\openin\myread=file.tex

\newcommand{\fileparse}{
 \loop
  \unless\ifeof\myread
  \immediate\read\myread to \fline
  \fline\\
 \repeat
}

\begin{document}

\immediate\read\myread to \fheader
\textbf{\fheader}\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 Col1 & Col2\\
 \fileparse
\end{tabular}

\immediate\closein\myread
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're loop is in a table cell -- which is a group. This can't work (at least not this way)

Comment: `\newwrite\myread` should be `\newread\myread` also you are missing `%` from ends of lines

Comment: @Christian: I see ... another restriction I did not know of ;-) Egreg has shown the workaround.

Comment: @David: The \myread is a copy&paste error. And for the % -- I never figure out where to put them, so far it did not get me into troble, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start a loop in a table cell and end it in another one. You can, instead, load all the lines in a token variable and deliver it at once when the loop is finished. The “ugly” `\unexpanded` can go in the definition of `\filewrite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newwrite\mywrite
\newread\myread

\newcommand{\filewrite}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\mywrite{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\fileparse}{%
 \toks0={}%
 \loop
  \unless\ifeof\myread
  \immediate\read\myread to \fline
  \toks0=\expandafter{\the\toks\expandafter0\expandafter\space\fline\\}%
 \repeat
 \the\toks0
}

\begin{document}

\immediate\openout\mywrite=\jobname-out.tex
\immediate\write\mywrite{Headline}

Hello World!
\filewrite{11 & 12}
\filewrite{21 & 22\textdegree}
\filewrite{31 & 32}

\immediate\closeout\mywrite

\openin\myread=\jobname-out.tex

\read\myread to \fheader
\textbf{\fheader}\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 Col1 & Col2\\
 \fileparse
\end{tabular}

\closein\myread
\end{document}
```

By the way, `\immediate` does nothing for read streams.

[image]

Comment: Works like a song - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX kernel has expandable loops (which in particular make no assignments whose scope would be limited by tabular cells), but they are not exposed for general use.

A oneliner can make them public. (their definitions are also almost one-liners actually). There are alternatives but why not use the available stuff. I chose a wrapper else the syntax may be unfamiliar looking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newwrite\mywrite
\newread\myread

\newcommand{\filewrite}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\mywrite{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*\Unless {}% check it does not exist
\makeatletter
  \long\def\Unless #1\repeat{\unless#1\@iwhilesw{\unless#1}\fi\fi}
\makeatother

% related: 
%  \long\def\SoLongAs #1\repeat{#1\@iwhilesw{#1}\fi\fi}

\newcommand{\fileparse}{%
 \Unless\ifeof\myread
    \read\myread to \fline
    \fline\\%
 \repeat
}

\begin{document}

\immediate\openout\mywrite=\jobname-out.tex
\immediate\write\mywrite{Headline}

Hello World!
\filewrite{11 & 12}
\filewrite{21 & 22\textdegree}
\filewrite{31 & 32}

\immediate\closeout\mywrite

\openin\myread=\jobname-out.tex

\read\myread to \fheader
\textbf{\fheader}\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 Col1 & Col2\\
 \fileparse
\end{tabular}

\closein\myread
\end{document}
```

[image]